# How do I set my samba share to allow guest users to view all folders and sub folders, including new and old

Tags: rhel, configuration, samba

I currently have a samba share set up on RHEL, that allows any user to write to the root folder.  I'm unable to write to the sub folders/files.  I have run:

```
chcon -R -t samba_share_t /path/to/samba/share
```

This allowed me to write to the "share" folder, but to none of the sub folders (apparently the -R flag didn't work?).

My desired outcome is this:

1. Anyone who accesses the samba share to be able to write to all folders/files.
2. If there are any new files/folders I create in my samba share directory, guests are by default able to right in/read from the new files/folders.

So if the answer involves me having to go in and change the permission to each new folder/file, then that doesn't work for me.

Here is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[global]

workgroup = MYGROUP
server string = Samba Server Version %v

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 50

security = share
passdb backend = tdbsam
guest account = nobody

=====Share Definitions====
 [homes] 
         comment = Home Directories
         browseable = no
         writable = yes

[folder1]
     comment = My first folder
     browseable = yes
     writable = yes
     guest ok = yes
     path = /my/path/
     wins support = yes
```